# Dev C++ Compiler Build error

Tags: c++

I am using a compiler called DevC++ version  5.1.0.0. It worked when i wrote programs in the beginning, but is now giving me a lot of trouble. Every time I execute a syntax error does not come up, however the program still does not execute, the program
works with visual c++ perfectly. What is the problem and please help as I spent hours on this already. What should I do?

The error looks like :

```
D:\Cpp\Assingnment 3\solution\2\Makefile.win [Error] [implementation.o] Error 1 (if this is the only error: please check your library includes)
```

I tried all the versions of Dev C+ but it shows the same.

The log file looks like:

```
Compiler: MinGW GCC 4.6.2 32-bit
Building Makefile: "D:\Cpp\Assingnment 3\solution\2\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
mingw32-make.exe -f "D:\Cpp\Assingnment 3\solution\2\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -c implementation.cpp -o implementation.o -I"E:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/include"   

'E:\DOCUME~1\@$L@' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
mingw32-make.exe: *** [implementation.o] Error 1

Execution terminated
```

The MakeFile.win contains:

```
# Project: Project1
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.1.1.0

CPP      = g++.exe
CC       = gcc.exe
WINDRES  = windres.exe
OBJ      = implementation.o main.o $(RES)
LINKOBJ  = implementation.o main.o $(RES)
LIBS     = -L"E:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib" -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  
INCS     = -I"E:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/include" 
CXXINCS  = -I"E:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/include" 
BIN      = Project1.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS)  
CFLAGS   = $(INCS)  
RM       = rm -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before Project1.exe all-after


clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o "Project1.exe" $(LIBS)

implementation.o: implementation.cpp
    $(CPP) -c implementation.cpp -o implementation.o $(CXXFLAGS)

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CPP) -c main.cpp -o main.o $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Comment: Try installing Dev-Cpp to C:\Dev-Cpp instead or any other directory which doesn't have spaces in the name.

Comment: The path of my dev c++ is E:\Dev-Cpp,although the path D:\Cpp\Assingnment 3\solution\2 is my assignment folder where the dev c++ project file is stored,I also changed the project folder name but the problem is the same

Comment: There should be other error messages besides that one

Comment: Bloodshed's Dev-C++ is way too old to do anything useful with. Please consider upgrading to one of its new forks: [Orwell Dev-C++](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.in/) or [wxDev-C++](http://wxdsgn.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: By the way, DevC++ is not a compiler, it is an IDE.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/ use tha

Comment: @legends2k: It may not be the newest but that doesn't mean it's "too old to do anything useful with". Please try not to make sensational statements to scare people.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, I think a beginner using an outdated compiler (part of the IDE) will only lead to picking up bad habits which will take time to unlearn, scaring away seemed to be the right thing to do. No, not a press reporter, didn't think I made anything sensational.

Comment: @legends2k: "scaring away seemed to be the right thing to do" "didn't think I made anything sensational" Make up your mind!

Comment: Regardless of supported standard, Dev C++ was also quite limited, the debugger in particular was crap. If you pick something modern like Codeblocks, it comes with modern versions of GCC and GDB per default, and you can always upgrade them since they aren't entwined with the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I've been researching and troubleshooting for 3 weeks.  But what I found was this:  Under 'execute' click 'clean'.  This worked for me.